# How to set "PreviousBuild" property of AssociateChanges activity in TFS Builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I would like to use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.AssociateChanges activity in our custom build definition (TFS2013 Update 2, VS2013, Git).

I'd like to set this activity's PreviousBuild property, of type IBuildDetail, to refer to a particular TFS build, say "CustomBuild_20151007.3".

**QUESTION**: **How do I set PreviousBuild property of AssociateChanges activity in the Properties window** (screenshot below), or do I have to create a custom build activity?

[image]

The [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.activities.associatechanges.previousbuild(v=vs.120).aspx) carries no sample code, and so far I've only seen IBuildDetail being obtained (in CodeActivity-derived classes) from CodeActivityContext. Any idea how to instantiate it for passing it as a Property value, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom build activity passing IBuildDetail parameters through tfs api.

IBuildDetail Interface from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail(v=vs.120).aspx

About how to use IBuildDetail, an example of query build definitions using IBuildDetail for reference：

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Auth with UserName & Password (Microsoft Acc):
        //BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(new NetworkCredential("xxx@hotmail.com", "pw"));
        //TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
        //tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;
        //
        //TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://code-inside.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"), tfsCred);

        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://code-inside.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"));

        IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfs.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));

        var builds = buildServer.QueryBuilds("DrinkHub");

        foreach (IBuildDetail build in builds)
        {
            var result = string.Format("Build {0}/{3} {4} - current status {1} - as of {2}",
                build.BuildDefinition.Name,
                build.Status.ToString(),
                build.FinishTime,
                build.LabelName,
                Environment.NewLine);

            System.Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        // Detailed via http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2012/09/fastest-way-to-get-list-of-builds-using-ibuildserver-querybuilds-2/

        var buildSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec("DrinkHub", "Main.Continuous");
        buildSpec.InformationTypes = null;
        var buildDetails = buildServer.QueryBuilds(buildSpec).Builds;

        Console.WriteLine(buildDetails.First().Status);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Patrick! I have marked your reply as the answer.

I still hope somebody can explain the purpose and use of the "Previous Build" property, as it's hard to believe that a field would be exposed as a property for no reason...